# Interpolating/Decimating CIC Filter Group Delay

Tags: filtering, finite-impulse-response, group-delay

I have an Interpolating [Cascaded Integrator Comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascaded_integrator%E2%80%93comb_filter) (CIC) filter designed as so:

```
Rate Change = 100
Number of Stages = 4
Differential Delay = 1
```

I'd like to calculate the **group delay** of this filter but I am not sure how.  [This question](https://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/127912-1.php) on DSP Related is helpful, but I am not sure my filter will have 0 delay.

Also, [Richard Lyons explanation is helpful](http://www.embedded.com/design/configurable-systems/4006446/Understanding-cascaded-integrator-comb-filters), but he doesn't directly deal with group delay.

I also have a Decimating CIC filter designed as so:

```
Rate Change = 25
Number of Stages = 4
Differential Delay = 1
```

How would I calculate its **group delay**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider an $D$-tap FIR filter with liner phase, the group delay (measured in samples) is $$g=\frac{D-1}{2}\tag{1}$$
and therefore, if it is measured in seconds it will be $$g=T_s\frac{D-1}{2}\tag{2}$$
where $T_s=1/F_s$.

The CIC filter which is also denoted as *recursive running sum* filter is indeed a special implementation of a moving-average filter. The moving average filter is
$$y[n]=\frac{1}{D}[1+z^{-1}+z^{-2}+\cdots z^{-D+1}]=\frac{1}{D}\sum_{n=0}^{D-1}z^{-n}=\frac{1}{D}\frac{1-z^{-D}}{1-z^{-1}}$$
which can be implemented by a $D$-tap FIR filter. If you compare carefully, the above response is identical to [the frequency response of each stage of a CIC filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascaded_integrator%E2%80%93comb_filter#The_CIC_filter).
Therefore, we can use $(1)$ and $(2)$ for calculation of the group delay in each stage.

Comparing the response given for moving average with that of the CIC filter, assuming $R$ is rate change and $M$ is the number of samples per stages, then $$D=RM$$ So for $N$ stages we have $$g_{\text{cic}}=N\left(\frac{RM-1}{2}\right)$$ expressed in samples and
$$g_{\text{cic}}=NT_s\left(\frac{RM-1}{2}\right)$$ in seconds.

Comment: The number of samples per stage of my filters is 1 (differential delay).  Should N be 1?  What would the group delay be for the two filters I describe?

Comment: in your case, $M=1$. Here $N$ is the number of stages.

Comment: This is true for interpolating filter. Would you add additional information for the decimating filter?

Comment: @jeremypatterson in the link I provided the system function is given for the general case (that is why it is said "R = decimation or interpolation ratio"). Can you explain why it is not true for decimating filter?

Comment: If I understand correctly, my example interpolating filter has 4*(100*1-1)/2 = 198 samples of delay.  For Decimation, I don't think it would have 4*(25*1-1)/2 = 48 samples of delay since the sample rate is significantly smaller after the filter.  Would I need to divide by R after the calculation for Decimation?

Comment: Ok. But can the fact that you ultimately decimate some samples change the group delay of the previous stage?

Comment: Yes, I think it will.  I think you answered my question. I'll keep thinking through the decimation filter. Thanks!

Comment: @jeremypatterson It is good to think about it. But I really don't think it will change anything. Just think about the last sample that is not decimated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46143/discussion-between-jeremypatterson-and-msm).