How to insert the pilot data in CDMA system with time varied channel
Generally, when using the OFDM system with time-varied channel, the pilot data is placed in such subcarriers of every symbol before informing the IFFT process. Then after the FFT process at the receiving end, these pilots can be used to estimate the channel in every symbol.
I am wondering about the CDMA system that is affected by the time-varied channel too. Is it feasible also to insert the pilot data in the same way of OFDM explained above? And how can the channel be estimated in case of CDMA system?
Notice
Based on my knowledge, such known spreading code will be transmitted to be used for channel estimation and synchronization. However, I don't think that will give the same performance of OFDM. Is that correct?

We can summarize channel estimation techniques as essentially probing the channel, and measuring the magnitude and phase of the transfer function for that channel. Our estimate will only be as good as the signal to noise ratio allows and importantly at the frequencies that are actually probed if we have a frequency varying channel (rich multipath with long delay spread). With a better SNR, we can get a better estimate, which then leads to temporal considerations: to the extent the channel is not varying in time, we can average successive measurements to improve our estimate. Further, this dictates to what extent our current estimate can be used for subsequent receptions.
That said consider the concept of “pilot” in CDMA vs OFDM and what that might represent: with OFDM we may allocate specific subcarriers as “pilots” but this means we can only estimate the channel at the frequencies where those subcarriers exist. As the time delay spread in the channel increases, the selectivity in frequency of the fading increases which means at some point the channel estimation at those particular  will be useless to the other subcarriers. What will be useful in this situation, and what OFDM allows us to do, is to send a complete known OFDM symbol (all subcarriers) as a pilot, allowing us to learn the channel for all the subcarriers, as limited only by the SNR of that symbol. The resulting equalizer for each sub-carrier is a simple “single-tap” equalizer as one of the primary motivators for using OFDM in a challenging multipath channel. If the channel is not sufficiently time varying, we could send a few OFDM symbols to average (improve) the channel estimate, as a trade with also being able to apply that correction to future symbols. Ultimately what I hope this illustrates are the trades and considerations involved in OFDM channel estimation and equalization.
While OFDM reduces a wideband channel to multiple parallel narrowband channels (and thus changing challenging frequency selective fading to the much more benign flat fading), CDMA instead provides “time compression” (as the time domain version of frequency spreading). Each CDMA symbol occupies the entire bandwidth, but the despreading operation resolves the multipath components in time from symbol to symbol such that they don’t overlap (what would otherwise be destructive inter-symbol interference). Under multipath conditions it would be feasible to delay and add the multipath components such as to recover as much as the signal as possible against the background noise (therefore SNR), and this approach has been commonly realized as a “Rake Receiver”. The implementation of the Rake and the realization of the coefficients for such combining really isn’t any different from classical channel estimation and equalization techniques for a wideband single carrier channel.
This leads to what could be done for CDMA and how does that compare to pilots in OFDM? To learn the channel we need to send a known waveform (or waveform with high enough SNR that we can count on decision directed approaches to basically say we know what was transmitted). If we use CDMA spreading codes that optimally spread their power evenly across the channel: these would be ideal for channel estimation assuming they can be received with sufficiently high SNR (so in a particular time interval it is only one code that is transmitted), or as alluded to earlier, make use of a slowly time varying channel and improve the estimate over multiple symbols. This would be similar to using an entire OFDM symbol to learn the channel at all frequencies assuming a challenging multipath channel.
What I hope I provided in this answer is further insight into the considerations in both the time delay spread of the channel (leading to selectivity in frequency) which is commonly referred to as “frequency selective fading” and “flat fading” and independently the frequency spread of the channel (leading to selectivity in time), which is more commonly referred to as “fast fading” and “slow fading”. These considerations drive the design of “pilot channels” and equalization for any communication system with consideration to individual channel bandwidths and receiver complexity.

Thank you. In the question I am considering the time-varied channel (which can also be considered constant during every symbol duration). So, in that case the pilot-subcarriers channel estimation would be efficient to track the channel effect. In of considering the channel to be slow fading, I agree that such symbols (not only in OFDM but any other system) can be transmitted to estimate the channel.
So, based on your explanation, rake receiver can be implemented in that case to track the channel effect in every symbol duration, could you please add details how can estimate the channel?

The pilot sub-carriers may not be sufficient to track the channel effect is my point. In OFDM if we only use a subset of the sub-carriers to learn the channel- then we will only learn the channel for those sub-carriers. If the entire channel is sufficiently "flat", meaning what you learn in one sub-carrier would apply to the other sub-carriers adjacent to it, then the approach is sufficient-- otherwise you may need to send an entire symbol to learn all the sub-carriers. The time varying consideration is independent of that-- that dictates how often you need to learn the channel.

Learning the channel in OFDM is very simple--- You know what the subcarrier needs to be. You know what you received (once you remove time and frequency offsets). The difference, in the FFT result, is the single-tap equalizer coefficient for that sub-carrier in terms of the magnitude and phase correction needed.   For learning the channel with CDMA, see this post: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/63141/how-determine-the-delay-in-my-signal-practically/63221#63221

I didn't get what you mean by "The pilot sub-carriers may not be sufficient to track the channel effect is my point." Do you mean the multipath effect? As I know, based of theoretical and experimental tests, the channel multipath effects can be estimated perfectly as long as the length of pilot length in each symbol is "at least" similar or longer than than the channel delay. In my opinion sending an entire symbol to track the channel in the scenario I described above is infeasible as the channel is varied from a symbol to another. For OFDM system, the process is clear and straightforward.

Regarding the link you shared, it's estimating the channel using the entire symbol. I agree with that case. What I mean, if we have the symbol duration of OFDM or any system 0.25 ms,  and we considered the channel to be constant during this duration only. Therefore, the use of pilot subcarriers in OFDM symbol can estimate the channel in each symbol whose duration is 0.25 ms, right? when transmitting the entire symbol in OFDM or CDMA to track the channel, the channel of estimated symbol of 0.25 ms can be totally different in the symbol carrying the data. I hope you got what I mean.

Consider each subcarrier represents only a very narrow portion of the entire channel bandwidth in OFDM (depending on total number of subcarriers). Therefore it can only truly estimate the channel for that particular narrow frequency only, not the entire channel. We can only estimate the channel where we illuminate it. If it doesn’t vary widely with frequency (flat fading) then no issue. If it does then it might be inadequate
